# LUA in software testing (automation tests)

Tags: lua

1. Does someone know to to attach Lua scripts in Jmeter or Junit?!
2. Can someone recommend some tutorials or books with Lua software testing?!
3. What do you think about Lua this is good scripting language and useful on market or this is garbage?!

Comment: 3. Lua is VERY powerful and, certainly, not garbage.  For 'smaller' to 'medium' size jobs I prefer Lua to Python (and that only due to lack of libraries, otherwise Lua would always come first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You embed Lua in your Java application with a library like [LuaJ](http://www.luaj.org/luaj/3.0/README.html) and work with Lua states there. Your JUnit tests simply wrap Java code which uses Lua.
2. [LuaUnit](http://luaunit.readthedocs.org) and [busted](http://olivinelabs.com/busted/) are well-documented frameworks for testing in Lua.
3. Lua is used in very popular, big games, like [WoW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Warcraft), [Garry's Mod](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garry%E2%80%99s_Mod), [Starbound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starbound), [GTA V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_V) and many more. It's one of the first choices for embedded systems and slowly finds his way into web development. All this because it's a very tiny and fast language and the only reason it's not more popular is the lack of libraries and documentations.

Comment: Probably OP wants to know is it worth to use Lua to solve his particular problem (automation tests) or should he stay with Java tools?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff From his question it seems he isn't experienced and his last subquestion sounds more general. Answering how testing with a host + scripting language works would end in a huge tutorial here.